# Select registros menores que a data e hora atual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma consulta a base dados onde os dados sejam menores que a data e hora atual

```
SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE agendamento < '".date('Y-m-d H:m:s')."'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a própria função do `MySQL`.

**Caso sua coluna possua hora:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM agenda
 WHERE agendamento < NOW()
```

> [`NOW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)
>
> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the current time zone.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a data e hora atual como o valor no formato 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' ou YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, dependendo do contexto em que a função é utilizada (string ou numérico). O valor é expresso na `time zone` atual.

[Pode testar aqui!](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_now)

**Caso sua coluna seja apenas de data:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM agenda
 WHERE agendamento < CURDATE()
```

> [`CURDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)
>
> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a data atual como o valor no formato 'YYYY-MM-DD' ou YYYYMMDD, dependendo do contexto em que a função é utilizada (string ou numérico).

Comment: @MarcosPaulo dessa forma você não precisará passar parâmetro. Mais simples e direto do que isso é impossível.

Comment: @Sorack , bem simples, porem estou trabalhando com uma empresa que tem a versão 5.5.53 do Mysql, e pelo que conheço do pessoal la, não poderei atualizar, pois existem outros sistemas funcionando

So descobri isso agora que coloquei a consulta que vc me passou e deu  erro 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

Comment: @MarcosPaulo a versão 5.5 também possui a função `NOW`. Provavelmente o erro está na forma em que você está montando a sua `string` com a `query`

Comment: puts, foi um pequeno vacilo, ficou uma aspas simples solta, agora não aparece o erro, porem não retornou nada

Comment: @MarcosPaulo cola aqui como ficou sua `query`

Comment: Retirei a data atual e coloquei ela separada , ai deu certo

Answer (score -2):

```
$today = date("d/m/Y");
$dia = date("d");
$mes = date("m");
$ano = date("Y");
$total = 0;

function selectAllPessoa(){
    $banco = abrirBanco(); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE status = 'N' AND(DAY(data_consulta)='$dia') AND (MONTH(data_consulta)) ORDER BY nome";
```

fiz assim por anos mas no meu codigo parou de fncionar tenta aí1